# Bottom border brush on groupbox is a different shade when the contained datagrid is larger than the groupbox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, mahapps.metro, visual-studio-2017

This one is driving me nuts.

I'm using Mahapps, and a secondary window that opens to display some data, some of the data is shown in datagrids which are placed in groupboxes.
Now, if I open the window and the data in the datagrid is so long that a scrollbar appears, the bottom line of the border gets darker...

[image: Shade]

I know its not a general issue, as other groupboxes with datagrid does not behave like this.
If I increase the burderthickness to 2, it doesn't happen.

I have tried adding a dockpanel/grid to the groupbox and moving the datagrid inside.
I also messed with the margins on the datagrid because i ran out of ideas.

This is the XAML:

```
       <GroupBox
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            BorderThickness="1"
            >
            <DockPanel>
                <DataGrid 
                ItemsSource="{Binding _DPW.EmployeeInDeptList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    x:Name="EmployeesInDeptList" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    CanUserAddRows="False" 
                    IsReadOnly="True" 
                    SelectionMode="Single">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ADFriendlyName}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DockPanel>

        </GroupBox>
```

I'm stumped...

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer: Adding a empty Grid row of a few pixels between the affected groupbox and the groupbox below it, solved the issue.

Its strange though that it only happened when the datagrid had to scroll.

I'm not even sure that it will make sense when I get my morning coffee in a few hours.